# 2 mandatory arguments in getopts in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

Execution of shell script which needs 2 mandatory arguments `-d` and `-v` 
and 1 optional argument `-h` not working accordingly

executing the script `store.sh` like below

```
store.sh -d <directory> -v<version>
```

I tried this like below, but its not working, the script is running with one argument also i.e `-d` without `-v`

```
while getopts "hd:v:" arg; do
  case "$arg" in
    h) usage 0;;
    d) DIRECTORY="$optarg"  ;;
    v) VERSION="$optarg" ;;
    *) usage 1;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is, but it should be `$OPTARG`, not `$optarg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the script with setting the DIRECTORY and VERSION to an empty string (better use lowercase for them, `directory` and `version`).
After the while loop check the variables:

```
test -z "${directory}" && usage 1
test -z "${version}" && usage 1
```

When you want to support empty directory/version, introduce an extra var `option_d_given`.